# How to tell Git that Mergetool Failed?

Tags: git

I'm running into this a lot. I need to merge branches, there's a conflict, so i use:

> git mergetool

My mergetool fires up and then it crashes, or more accurately I get confused because I'm new to VIM and end up killing the merge.

Now if I try to run git mergetool again, it will tell me everything has been merged, but that's not the case. If I open up the file, I still see

```
v<<<<<<< HEAD
v1
=======
v2
>>>>>>> master
```

How do I tell it that the mergetool failed and that it has not been merged? In otherwords how do I get git mergetools to fire up my merge tool rather than tell me no files need merging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a recent enough Git, you should be able to do:

```
git update-index --unresolve <path/to/messed/up/merge>
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much, this had been driving me crazy! I'd vote up your answer if I could :)

Comment: @newUserNameHere: You can, now.

Comment: Saved my day, thank you ! (accenditently pressed ctrl-w instead of ctrl-s in mergetool)